# NSDate Comparison Failing when using "==" operator

Tags: core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, foundation

I am comparing two dates using the operator "==", and even through **two dates are same** the expression returns false

Here's how I do the comparison:

```
date1 == date2  // this returns false
date1 < date2  // this returns true
```

However if I do the below checks for dates it returns **True**

```
date1.timeIntervalSince1970 == date2.timeIntervalSince1970 // returns true
```

Even the Calendar check to granularity set to nanoseconds returns true

```
Calendar.current.isDate(date1, equalTo: date2, toGranularity: .nanosecond) // this also returns true
```

So I am wondering why the comparison operator is returning false.

**For context:**
I am trying to find a specific date in Core Data records using the following Predicate:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "rawDate = %@", extractedDate as NSDate)
```

Can anyone point out why dates might not be equal ? As I have spent tons of hours debugging on this and still no solution

Comment: What are the dates in the SQLite file?

Comment: Well I don't know how to check that.... will search on how to do this and report back